# How can I write a polite reminder letter?

Tags: editing

Can anyone please help me about creating a reminder letter, I sent a payment email 15 days ago. Now how can I write a polite reminder letter to the related organization?

Comment: Welcome to Writers.  Sorry, but asking *what* to write is off-topic here; we're more focused on *how*.  Please check out our short [tour].  Thanks for understanding.

Answer (score 1):

Here you have touched on a very sensitive part of doing business: Making sure you get your due while at the same time keeping the business relation healthy and nice.

Please be aware that there are early payers, late payers and non-payers out there. The last category is dangerous for any business.

A quick search via google using "*creditor reminder sample letter*" got me 263,000 results. You are not the first person dealing with this problem.

***Good luck!***

A sample:
http://www.letters.org/collection-letter/collection-letter.html

> **DOS AND DON’T’S OF COLLECTION LETTER**
>
> - A Collection Letter should be written well before the payment due date so that it gives enough time to the debtor to arrange for the funds
> - It should be short and brief
> - The letter should only talk about the current payment due or about any pending payments only
> - Even though the creditor writes this letter, the tone of the letter should not be rude or insulting or humiliating or threatening. The creditor must not forget that the debtor has taken money under some compulsions
>
> ***etc.***

---

> **SAMPLE COLLECTION LETTER**
>
> _________________ (Name and address of debtor)
>
> ________________ (Date)
>
> Subject: Reminder for collection against first installment
>
> Dear Ms/Mr ___________
>
> This is with reference to the loan that you have taken from our institution vide docket number _____________ dated ____________.
>
> We would like to inform you that your first installment is due on _________ (date) as per the loan agreement. This is a payment collection reminder for the same.
>
> Please let us know how and by when will the payment be made to us. Alternatively we can also send our representative to collect the payment from you at a time convenient to you.
>
> ***etc.***